# Read Merge Cell of Excel in BIRT

Tags: excel, merge, birt

I am trying to read an excel file from BIRT using jxl library. I read the file and extract the data from it as well. But I am not able to read the file with merge cells. If merge cells are present in the excel file then I want to create merge cells dynamically in the BIRT template at runtime as well. Is there any way to read the merge cells from the excel file in BIRT (preferably using JS) and dynamically create merge cell in the table at BIRT side.

Do I need to write the code in beforeFactory event?

I have attached the image of Excel file for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: I can't help you with your problem, but there are different Excel options in different versions of BIRT.  You need to identify what version of BIRT you are using.

Comment: I am using BIRT 4.3.1 with Eclipse Kepler. As I mentioned, I am using Excel data source and jxl library to extract the content of excel file but I am not sure how to handle merge cell case.